# Updating pseudo-element content property when HTMLElement.dataset updates

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I am using the CSS `attr` function to dynamically link the value of a `data-*` attribute to the content of a pseudo element:

```
body::after { content: attr(data-after) }
```

I am then regularly updating that data attribute via the `HTMLElement.dataset` property:

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.body.dataset.after = new Date;
}, 1000);
```

I'm noticing that in Internet Explorer, though all of these features are supported, the pseudo-element is not having its content property updated to reflect the most recent changes.

I have built a fiddle to demonstrate the problem. You may view it [online here](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/cw579ukv/).

What can I do to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a known bug/limitation in Internet Explorer right now that causes pseudo elements to *not* be updated when datasets update. A sufficient work-around is to instead update the attributes with the older (and thus more broadly supported) `setAttribute` method:

```
setInterval(function () {
    // Work-around for IE bug: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28031707
    document.body.setAttribute( "data-after", new Date );
}, 1000 );
```

You can [see the results here](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/cw579ukv/1/).

A bug has been filed against this issue internally and the appropriate feature teams should be evaluating the matter in an upcoming triage. As soon as possible, we will have dev-cycles allocated for resolving the matter.

Comment: Do you know which versions of IE are affected?

Comment: HTMLElement.dataset was added in IE11. Currently the in development version of IE is also affected, though I did file a bug on it today.

Comment: Got the same problem but unfortunately I did not find your answer during my research on Internet and on SO before I figured out the workaround by myself :(. Issue is still present in IE by now.

Answer (score 0):

IE tends to have a lot of issues.

jQuery is a popular JavaScript library created with solving cross-browser issues in-mind. You can use jQuery's .attr() function to set your data attributes, like so:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('body').attr('data-after', new Date());
}, 1000);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Alternatively, you can look into using jQuery's `.data([key], [value])` method.

Note: Be careful using dates with Internet Explorer, in my experience its unable to parse some common ISO 8601 date formats. I'd suggest another library for handling dates and times: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: jQuery `.data()` method doesn't update the data attribute which is used for CSS content pseudo element property